# Missing Shadows

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I have a problem:

In material mode, this little medium-poly Miata casts a shadow on the ground.

When I press Render, the Miata's shadow disappears.

Is there any way to get the shadow back?

[image: The render... no shadow!]

[image: Material Mode... yes shadow!]

Comment: Disabling the "shadows" option in the rendering panel under "shading" behaves like that (also in 2.76) ... maybe?

Comment: This could have quite a number of reasons (animation on light source or other objects, various render settings and natural differences between openGL preview and actual render). To preview a scene properly, its best to use the render preview mode (Shift + Z). If you're still encountering problems, please load a blendfile to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit your question to add the link.